# Making a custom bathtub, using fibreglass and a suitable high-strength smooth coating

Tags: bathtub, trim, materials, renovation

## The problem

I'd like to fit a custom quite sizeable (2000 x 1100 x 550 ish) bathtub. The room won't take anything except custom, which is either horribly expensive or self-made, so I'm looking optimistically at alternatives. I don't have the facilities for blowing 3 x 2.5m acrylic sheet into a self made mold, so I have to look at alternatives. But even self-made, I'd like to be done *well*. This is roughly where my thinking is at. Will it work? If so, how do I do the parts Im not sure about, and what materials would work best?

## My planned process so far

I do a lot of DIY and craftwork, so while this is a bit of a project, it's not too bad, if I know what I'm doing.

Firstly, I am reasonably confident that I can make a good quality mold of the desired inner surface or the bathtub. I would expect that with a suitable release agent (wax, silicone spray, etc) I can fibreglass coat the exterior, and end up with a fibreglass cast of the shape I want, adding as many layers as needed for strength.

So I have a rough fibreglass bathtub. Cutting holes is easy. I don't know how rough the fibreglass will be, I'll make the mold as smooth as I can, but who can tell what the raw fibreglass tub will end up like.

## Unresolved issues

Either way, there are 2 issues remaining - resilience/strength/support, from below, and smooth high quality surface internally.

- **From below**, I have a few options, but very open to alternatives. I can thicken and strengthen the fibreglass and use the usual plywood sheet on battens/legs, underneath the flat bottom, or... what else would work?
- **From inside**, I'm very wary of fibreglass as a bathtub surface. It's porosity isn't good, it discolours, it's hard to clean, and it isn't as nice looking as materials such as acrylics or other ordinary bathtub plastics. I've read several sites that say you can refinish a fibreglass bathtub with acrylic coating (gel exists but I wouldn't touch it, doesnt last as well), and companies exist that say they can refinish an old tub (be it acrylic, fibreglass or whatever) with new acrylic coating.  So I'd like to do something like that, a hard, cleanable, durable, totally non-porous, maybe glossy/satin, ideally somewhat self-smoothing material (paint on, or coat and allow to drain off?) that will bond to fibreglass and create a good coat suitable for a bathtub. It would have to be able to resist minimal flexing without cracking, I guess, as people get in and out, or could slip.

As an alternative, I also have access to industrial size quantities (5 - 50kg) of heavy duty non-runny epoxy resin, and could use that on the mold instead of fibreglass. Or indeed, any other material - plaster of paris? Layer of cement?

I'd like to keep weight down so steel is out, but no issues with say, 6-8mm polycarbonate sheets or aluminium sheet, as strengtheners. I'd probably avoid expanding foam as it degrades over time, and may not have enough strength, for small localised pressure (foot when getting into bath). But perhaps its a good idea. Don't know.

## My questions on this

So I think I have 3 main areas of question...

- **Making the raw tub from a mold** - What release agent, and what raw material ?(fibreglass, epoxy, or other?)
- **Strengtheners below** - just make the raw cast stronger and use plywood below, or add strengtheners of some kind? If the latter, what to use?
- **Finishing of visible surfaces** - what are my options? If the original mold is good, then well laid fibreglass or epoxy won't be difficult to get roughly right, but how do I take it from there, to some kind of finished bathtub with a more usual type of durable very smooth surface? What materials to use? Or do I just pay a refinishing company to handle that stage, as they would any other bathtub?
- **Is any finishing required** (polishing, buffing etc) or does it dry smooth and pristine? If needed, what's usual? And related, at what point do I cut holes? (When the raw cast is done, or when it's coated and finished?)

I'm in the UK if that helps, and it isn't likely to hit barriers for affording good materials if I self-make. Thanks!

Comment: Make in-situ or in workshop, will it fit to get it into bathroom?

Comment: Garage. I'll move it in when its ready and done. I hadn't overlooked that ;;)

Comment: A) This is too broad, too many questions all in one. B) Your princess is in another castle - look at custom car sites. They do custom, one-off fiberglass car bodies _all_ the time that are huge, single pieces, and _can_ come out of the mold with an almost perfect, ready-to-paint finish. That's where you need to be looking for your advice.

Comment: It will be expensive (certainly in labor, probably also in materials) as a DIY if you want any quality to it. Molds are wicked expensive if you only use them once... Look to boatbuilding sites for ideas, but do consider using epoxy rather than polyester for your resin (costs a bit more, stinks a lot less.) Stock smooth finish is "gel-coat" on a smooth mold overlaid with the fiberglass/resin, not fiberglass/resin sprayed with gel-coat (gel coat needs to be cured without air to work right, as far as I recall.) Fibreglass and resin are used together as a composite system - that's not either/or.

Comment: For support below, just buy a bag or two of plaster and bed it like any other plastic tub should be. Some folks use foam these days, I'm wary of it.  Every "acrylic" tub I've ever met in person is overlaid with fibreglass on the non-show side for reinforcement. I wonder if you could vacuum+heat mold an acrylic sheet to get good smooth surface (nothing touches the show side in molding) without a too-complex mold, and then fiberglass the outside of that like the factories do.

Comment: @Freeman - Im not a car person, i hadnt any idea of that. Ask them for technique, or to do it?  But its only really one question - how best to do it, to get a good result. The rest is just the usual outlining the research ive already done, and points that especially matter in an answer.

Comment: You might look for a local custom car shop and ask them to do it, but it won't be cheap. Or you could search out the custom car forums and research how to make the bucks (forms) and what the process is to lay up your own fiberglass "car body". Bear in mind that the Porsche 356 (from the 50s & 60s) was called the "bathtub Porsche" for the general shape of its body! :) Of course, it was made from metal, not fiberglass, but it's a shape the car pros will, in general, be familiar with. Plus a fiberglass layup is a fiberglass layup, no matter the final shape.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - plaster support sounds perfect, i too am very wary of foam support, or gel finish, and wouldnt use. Mold though i can make myself, that oddly wont be too hard or expensive. You reckon use epoxy rather than fibreglass for the actual cast? Or just use epoxy as the fibreglass resin, rather than the usual polyester resin? I don't quite understand what you suggest there. I wont be able to heat mold. Too big. Not a chance.

Comment: @Freeman, what would appropriate search terms be, for that? Im not familiwr with car body modder / aftermarket custom body shop, terminology

Comment: I think that what you just typed would probably get you started. Try "custom car", "body shop", "car body fabricator", "DIY fiberglass car body", etc. I've watched many shows where they do the work, so I get the general steps, but it's not something I've ever attempted myself. Of course, they make it look easy, but I'm sure it's not that easy, especially the first time...

Answer (score 0):

I refinish cast iron, fiberglass and steel enamel bathtubs and also do custom fiberglass designs. What you are wanting to do is not that expensive. The main thing to worry about is that it must be strong enough to support the weight of the water. That said, design comes first.

Comment: That's good to know, but the question asks for details and how to, not just "yes its possible".  Can you add detail to your answer? Thank you!